# How to get initwithDictionary data into NSObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift2

I created `NSObject` class but I don't know how to convert `Objective-C` method into `Swift-2`.How to call `NSObject` method of other ViewController and how to write this method with `Swift-2`?

Sample Objective-C code:

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)data
{
     self=[super init];
     if (self) {
        NSString*action=[data objectForKey:@"action"];
        NSString*status=[data objectForKey:@"status"];

         if (NotNull(status)) {
             self.status=[status intValue];
         }
         if (NotNull(action)) {
             self.action=action;
         }
     }
     return self;
}
```

Can you help me about this subject?
Thank you.

Comment: Which part is difficult?  If you want to rewrite it in Swift, read some Swift tutorials and then rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
init(dictionary : [String : AnyObject]) {
    super.init()

    self.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
}
```